# jQuery SlidesJS plugin does not display when called in a div

Tags: jquery, css, html, plugins, slideshow

I am using the SlideJS plugin from http://slidesjs.com.

It works perfectly fine when the `slideshow.htm` page is opened in a browser.

However, the problem arises when I try to load this page into a `div#main` on my homepage. Only the outer frame of the slideshow along with the left and right scroll buttons are displayed. The actual slides from the slideshow are not displayed at all.

However, if I try to display any other webpage in this `div#main`, it displays fine.

Here is the code of `slideshow.htm`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slidecss/global.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true
        });
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> 
<div id="example"> 
<div id="slides"> 
  <div class="slides_container"> <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"> 
    <img src="img/slide-2.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 2"> <img src="img/slide-3.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 3"> 
    <img src="img/slide-4.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 4"> <img src="img/slide-5.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 5"> 
    <img src="img/slide-6.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 6"> <img src="img/slide-7.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 7"> 
  </div>
  <!--slides_container -->
  <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="img/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a> 
  <a href="#" class="next"><img src="img/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a> 
</div>
<!--slides-->
<img src="img/example-frame.png" width="739" height="341" alt="Example Frame" id="frame"> 
</div>
<!--example -->
</div>
```

Here's the CSS code used by `slideshow.htm`:

```
#container {
width:580px;
padding:10px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
}

#example {
width:600px;
height:350px;
position:relative;
}


#frame {
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
width:739px;
height:341px;
top:-3px;
left:-80px;
}

/*
Slideshow
*/

#slides {
position:absolute;
top:15px;
left:4px;
z-index:100;
}

/*
Slides container
Important:
Set the width of your slides container
Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/

.slides_container {
width:570px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
display:none;

}

/*
Each slide
Important:
Set the width of your slides
If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
Set to display block
*/

.slides_container a {
width:570px;
height:270px;
display:block;
}


.slides_container a img {
display:block;
}



#slides .next,#slides .prev {
position:absolute;
top:107px;
left:-39px;
width:24px;
height:43px;
display:block;
z-index:101;
}

#slides .next {
left:585px;
}
```

Here I call `loadHome()` which loads the `slideshow.htm` page into `div#main`:

```
<li class=""><a href="" id="home" onclick="return loadHome()">Home</a></li>
```

Here's the `loadHome()` code getting `slideshow.htm`:

```
function loadHome() {
    var xmlhttp = createobject();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","slideshow.htm",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's the CSS of `div#main`:

```
#main{
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #95a5bf;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant html and script? This would make it much easier to help you out. You can, if you want, even add a fiddle on jsFiddle.net.

Comment: I have just posted the relevant html & scripts. Pls help

Comment: Can anybody pls help me with this?

Comment: You need to call the .slides function in your success function callback.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been having a similar problem with this, My slideshow sits inside a div wrapper which has display set to none.When  faded in using jquery, images dont display as expected.

I've found out that if i change the div's display to block in the css then the slide show works fine.

No good for what im trying to do but maybe it might help someone else to find a solution